# Unable to send/attach files to ms bot in teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

When attaching files to ms bot in teams, it is not allowing. Also files tabs is missing in bot. When i try to drag and drop files to bot i am unable to do so.

all the above behavior is in one to one chat. (in MS Teams)
Teams is a channel configured in Azure and the bot added in Microsoft Teams.

Is there any configuration missing or code needs to be done.

Help is much appreciated .

Answer (score 4):

Update your manifest to V1.3 and add `supportsFiles` flag in the Bot configuration so that the "upload" button starts showing up in 1:1 Chats with the Bot. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files#configure-your-bot-to-support-files) is the documentation for the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will check it.

Comment: @poovarasan Did this fix your issue?

Comment: Thanks! Very common to have supportsFiles: false in your manifest